# OSError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in C:\Users\Lior\.kaggle. Or use the environment method

Tags: python, pip, kaggle

I have a similar problem as: [Kaggle API issue "Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in......"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822265/kaggle-api-issue-could-not-find-kaggle-json-make-sure-its-located-in)

I have the same error when I type `kaggle competitions download -c spaceship-titanic`

But in my case the folder ".kaggle/" is actually empty. So I assume I downloded kaggle api incorrectly, how I download it correctly?

Things I have tried acccording to https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api

`pip install kaggle`, `pip install --user kaggle`, `sudo pip install kaggle`

The first two compiled, but didnot create the kaggle.json file.

The third didnot compiled and it said sudo command not found.

Comment: Your json will come only after you generate the API from account in Kaggle. You need to do this step 2. Setting up the API token mentioned in https://adityashrm21.github.io/Setting-Up-Kaggle/

Comment: I alredy have an account. I dont success with step 2 in this mannual. Firstly, I didn't find the "your profile" button he talks about ... but I found a button that leads to my profile so I assumed it is it. And inside my profile page I didn't found anything about api.

Comment: login to kaggle. On the top right there is a small icon, click that. Then select account. under account. you will see API option. in that you can select create new api token

Comment: The `sudo` command is a *nix `sh` command, and subsequently will not exist on Windows. The win equivalent would be to open Command Prompt/PowerShell as Admin then run the Python command - However, Python modules should not need admin permissions and should not be used to install packages

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample photo for finding the accounts page]

Sample photo for finding the accounts page